# How to use kwarg arguments when evaluating a function using map functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, python-itertools, functools

Below is an example of a `test` method which is evaluated using a for loop and a kwarg argument.

```
def test(first_arg='_', second_arg='_'):
    return 'first_arg: %s\t second_arg: %s' % (first_arg, second_arg)

strings = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

for s in strings:
    print(test(second_arg=s))
```

**How can the same result be achieved using map functionality?
That is, how can a kwarg be passed into the `map` function?:**

```
for i in map(test, strings):
    print(i)
```

The order of the arguments in the `test` function cannot be changed and passing all arguments is not acceptable. That is, the below map-equivalent solutions are not desired:

```
# Passing two arguments is not a desired solution.
for s in strings:
    print(test(first_arg='_', second_arg=s))
```

OR

```
# Editing the order of kwargs is also not possible.
def test(second_arg='_', first_arg='_'):
    return 'first_arg: %s\t second_arg: %s' % (first_arg, second_arg)

for s in strings:
    print(test(s))
```

Comment: You could use `partial` and provide the first argument explicitly: `from functools import partial; map(partial(test, '_'), strings)`. Obviously this requires you to know the correct default value (but you can access this via introspection if you want to be future-proof).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lambda` to create a new function that calls `test`() with `second_arg=x` using its only argument `x` :

```
for i in map(lambda x: test(second_arg=x),  strings):
    print(i)
```

the output:

```
first_arg: _     second_arg: a
first_arg: _     second_arg: b
first_arg: _     second_arg: c
first_arg: _     second_arg: d
first_arg: _     second_arg: e
```

is the same as for this:

```
for s in strings:
    print(test(second_arg=s))
```

Output:

```
first_arg: _     second_arg: a
first_arg: _     second_arg: b
first_arg: _     second_arg: c
first_arg: _     second_arg: d
first_arg: _     second_arg: e
```

Alternatively, you can define a helper function. This is equivalent to the solutions with `lambda` above:

```
def call_with_second(x):
    return test(second_arg=x)

for i in map(call_with_second,  strings):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
first_arg: _     second_arg: a
first_arg: _     second_arg: b
first_arg: _     second_arg: c
first_arg: _     second_arg: d
first_arg: _     second_arg: e
```